# The system returned: (104) connection reset by peer

Tags: php, hosting, squid

Facing a squid error. This is the error message we are getting.

Read Error
'The system returned: (104) connection reset by peer.

Our web product is hosted on godaddy. The whole website is working completely alright except this one page on which we are facing the error.
the page times out exactly after the 15 secs.
On testing the same page on localhost it works completely alright, but the same page when tested on server is timed out.
Can anybody suggest us an solution?
Breaking our heads from past many hours.
thanks in advance.
link for the page we are getting the error : http://silicongem.com/rhea/testrd.php
for authentication you can use username: demo 
                               password: demo1
Snapshot:
[image: Snapshot]

Comment: I have the very same issue... how did you solve yours, cause I can see yours works fine now. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Well my servers were not upto the mark. I had to change the server. Since, old servers were not able to compute too many operations in few seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Some time a bad Squid config can also cause this. Please check if you have correct memory config defined. These are few important settings to keep your Squid healthy -

```
max_stale 24 hour
cache_mem 1500 MB
memory_replacement_policy lru
cache_replacement_policy lru
cache_swap_low 93
cache_swap_high 97
positive_dns_ttl 24 hours
negative_dns_ttl 1 minute
quick_abort_min 0 KB
quick_abort_max 0 KB
```

You may find documentation here by replacing each directive at the end -
http://www.squid-cache.org/Doc/config/cache_swap_low/